# Mariadb alongside MySQL Can't start the MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu

I'm running MySQL on ubuntu 14.04 and it works great.

For development and testing before switching between the two I want to install a separate Mariadb server.

I followed this (old) tutorial: [Installing MariaDB Alongside MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/installing-mariadb-alongside-mysql/)

Everything was done carefully with a 10.0.21 compiled binaries until I try to start the mariadb:

`# /etc/init.d/mariadb start`

Instead of printing `[ OK ]` it prints `.*`. I went to the error log in the data folder and found two types of errors depending on the installed mysql server:

1. If mysql was running -> `mysql_safe A mysqld process already exists`.
2. I  mysql was not running -> `File './mysql-bin.index' not found (Errorcode: 13 Permission denied)`

I think the Mariadb is trying to use the wrong pid file and I have no clue how to fix that - Any Ideas?

Comment: Well, I guess one thing to try might be edit `/etc/init.d/mariadb` and see where it attempts to use MySQL files. However, in this day and age I would simply run the two in separate Docker containers.